# How to Emulate Google Earth globe with Google Maps Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google Maps now includes an ["Earth"](https://www.google.com/maps/@20.8119959,-67.721141,22947494m/data=!3m1!1e3) setting similar to the Google Earth Plugin. I was hoping to replace the Google Earth Plugin with this feature since it has more modern touch interaction and is continually being updated, but it's not built into the Google Maps API so far as I can tell.

I've done a fair amount of searching on it, but I've only ever gotten results for the Google Earth Plugin API and the Satellite view in Google Map, which doesn't give me the 3D globe that I'm hoping for.

Is there any way to accomplish the Google Earth Style globe like Google has in a simpler way than drudging through and trying to make sense of the minified javascript on the Google Maps site?

Answer (score 0):

No, at least not with the Google Maps API at the present time.  'Earth' is not one of the supported map types yet; see 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeId